# Xamarin.Forms: add labels inside ListView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.forms.listview

I'm still learning, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to display a `ListView` in my `Xamarin.Form`. So far, this is what I have, and it works pretty well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GasStations"
             x:Class="GasStations.MainPage">
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets">
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the codebehind:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(coord);
List<String> storeList = new List<String>();
string store = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in ((JArray)obj))
{
    store = item.Value<string>("name");
    //desc = item.Value<string>("description"); /* This is the string I want to display */
    storeList.Add(store);
}
ListView_Pets.ItemsSource = storeList;
```

It works and it shows the store names in the `ListView`. You can see the [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCrbf.png).

Now, instead of just showing the store `Name` in the `ListView` I want to also display the description (and any other values). I assume I would need `Labels` in each row, similar to the `asp.net` `GridView` `ItemTemplate`.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't build:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GasStations"
             x:Class="GasStations.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets" ItemsSource="{Binding MyClass}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Label x:Name="Label_Name" Text="Name" />
                            <Label x:Name="Label_Desc" Text="Description" />
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I have access to both `Name` and `Description` in the codebehind (with `desc = item.Value<string>("description");`, but I don't know how to bind these values to the Labels in the Form.

Comment: You are not using the advantages of MVVM paradigm. As indicated on the answer specify the required bindings to your newly added labels. x:name breaks the pattern MVVM so try to stay away from it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54280876/5772095 ... that does it for you.

Comment: "but it doesn't build" - what build errors are you getting?

Comment: @Jason, His `xaml` had `ViewCell` twice and I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the *Binding*.. Amusing the properties in your class are  `Name` and `Description` then you would do this

```
<Label x:Name="Label_Name" Text="{Binding Name}" />
<Label x:Name="Label_Desc" Text="{Binding Description}" />
```

***Note*** : you don't need to use x:Name unless you need to access them directly from Code-Behind

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
<Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
```

**Updated**

> Thanks for your answer. But what would I need to do in the codebehind?
>   To what object would I bind them?

When you specify binding in a `ItemTemplate`, you are binding to the individual properties of the class in the list your `listview` has specified as the `ItemsSource`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what would I need to do in the codebehind? To what object would I bind them?

Answer (score 1):

**Define the Class with Properties**

```
public MyClass(){

public string Name{get;set;}
public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

**After then In code Behind**

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(coord);
ListView_Pets.ItemsSource = obj;
```

**Then update in List View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GasStations"
             x:Class="GasStations.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell>
                          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                          </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete example, it really helped me. Please fix the syntax errors in the xaml.

Answer (score 1):

In the Ankit tyagi's code, they wrote two `viewcell` in his xaml. delete one of them.
There are completly create  processes of binding data to a listview .

First of all define your model.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, define a datasource in the back code.I suggest you to use ObservableCollection to collect your data.
ObservableCollection is a generic dynamic data collection that provides notifications (using an interface "INotifyCollectionChanged") when items get added, removed, or when the whole collection is refreshed

```
         public ObservableCollection<MyClass> DataSource { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.BindingContext = this;

        DataSource = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();

        DataSource.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Item 1", Description = "Sub Item Text 1" });
        DataSource.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Item 2", Description = "Sub Item Text 2" });
        DataSource.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Item 3", Description = "Sub Item Text 3" });


        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In the end, difine a listview in your xaml. do not forget to binding the source data from the back code.

```
    <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" 
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              SeparatorColor="Silver">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                             <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        </StackLayout>

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Running of these code.

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that you manually add to the `datasource` while Ankit tyagi's code takes object `coord` and automatically copies to `MyClass` with `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(coord);`.

Comment: Can this be done with `ObservableCollection` or do I need to loop through the collection and add it individually to `DataSource` with `DataSource.Add`?

Comment: Yes, this can be done with `ObservableCollection`, you need to loop through the collection and add it individually to `DataSource` with `DataSource.Add`.